# Slim Framework - Calling halt in the new version 1.6

Tags: php, mysql, slim

I upgraded Slim from 1.5 to 1.6 of late.

Everything is working fine. But the application is breaking at halt call. No error logs.
Just returns blank. No error message or anything.

Anyone had this issue before?

Comment: I'd recommend trying their forums. You may have better luck.  http://help.slimframework.com/

Comment: have you enabled the debug option when instantiating Slim?